# Unity Making a selectable 3D earth

Tags: unity-game-engine

We want to teach certain concepts to students with a little game. I put a 3D Circle on the Unity game engine. I want to break this into nine. I want to adapt each concept as if it were a world continent.

Question:  A 3D-dimensional world will be divided into 9 parts, each of which will be a continent. With the mouse on the top I can select the mouse with the right and left I want to choose what I want to rotate. Normal FPS games can choose to consider as the map. Thank you..

Comment: This is too broad question . You can create a sphere (aka 3D-circle), then put some texture, when mouse is clicked over this sphere, try to figure out using `RayCast`/`RaycastHit` . On that event disable that earth and enable previously created 9 continent. I guess, this will be enough.

Comment: Actually I found it. Want to make interactive 3d earth..